# Save only a certain part of an HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Is it possible to save or export only a certain part of the canvas rather than the whole canvas?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmvYh.jpg

At the moment, when I save the file I get the composition plus the transparent background (light blue in example above) of the entire canvas element I have on the site. What I would like to get is only the gray region (which could be made up of several images and text elements).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract a portion of an image in canvas and use it as background image for a div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35033357/how-do-i-extract-a-portion-of-an-image-in-canvas-and-use-it-as-background-image)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes you can. Here is [**the JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/WebWanderer/d9j1gufv/1/).

First, you need to take a `clipping` of the image in your canvas. This is pretty simple. I made another canvas (a hidden one) and used the `context.drawImage`

```
var hidden_ctx = hidden_canvas.getContext('2d');

hidden_ctx.drawImage(
    MainCanvas,
    startClippingX,
    startClippingY,
    clippingWidth,
    clippingHeight,
    pasteX,
    pasteY,
    pasteWidth,
    pasteHeight
);
```

Now, we need the Data URL from this canvas so we can download the contents. For this, we will use the `canvas.toDataURL` method.

```
var data_url = hidden_canv.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Now, all we need to do is make a download link (an `a` element with an `href` attribute of our `data_url`) and we're done!

Comment: Ok, got the concept of the creating invisible canvas and this should work pretty well. Now since this was super simplified case, I'm wondering if its possible to get coordinates of all the objects in canvas (directly from canvas, not looping throu variables) so I could find top left + bottom right positions (to get height and width ) http://oi62.tinypic.com/33bintd.jpg?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking here, could you be more specific? Also, `canvas` doesn't contain "objects." Once anything has been drawn on a canvas, it is nothing more than an array of pixels. There is no collection of draw path history kept anywhere in the context. If you want to keep a reference of the paths you've drawn on a canvas, or your "objects", you will need to do so yourself, retain your information in an array, and you will need to loop through that array.

Comment: Cool. Glad to help @mindo. Would much appreciate the accepted answer. If you have any more questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you @WebWanderer .. You really saved my day.

Answer (score 12):

Suppose you have a canvas called `oldCanvas` and you want to save a rectangular area of width `w` and height `h` with its upper left corner at `x, y`.

Start by making a new `canvas` element of width `w` and height `h`:

```
var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
newCanvas.width = w;
newCanvas.height = h;
```

Now copy the rectangular area to the new canvas:

```
var newContext = newCanvas.getContext('2d');
newContext.drawImage(oldCanvas, x, y, w, h, 0, 0, w, h);
```

Finally, save the new canvas using [`toDataUrl()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) or whatever method you were using previously to save a whole canvas.

For example, you can make an image out of the new canvas:

```
var newImage = document.createElement('img');
newImage.src = newCanvas.toDataURL();
```

Then append the new image to the web page:

```
document.body.appendChild(newImage);
```

Or maybe you have a container `div` that you want to append it to.

In any case, once the image is in the document, you can right-click on it and save it as usual.

I've implemented this approach in the following snippet. When you run it, a canvas will be randomly painted. Click and drag on the canvas to select a region that you want to download. A new, downloadable image appears at right.

```js
// Returns a random RGB string (RGBA if alpha is true).
function randomColor(alpha) {
  var rgb = [
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 255),
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 255),
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)
  ];
  if (alpha) {
    rgb.push(Math.random());
  }
  return 'rgb' + (alpha ? 'a' : '') + '(' + rgb.join(', ') + ')';
}

// Makes a random picture for use in the demonstration.
function makeCanvas() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('oldCanvas'),
      context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
      width = canvas.width = 400,
      height = canvas.height = 500;
  context.fillStyle = randomColor();
  context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
  for (var i = 0; i < 200; ++i) {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * width),
        y = Math.floor(Math.random() * height),
        w = Math.floor(Math.random() * width/5),
        h = Math.floor(Math.random() * height/5);
    context.fillStyle = randomColor(true);
    if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) === 0) {
      context.fillRect(x - w / 2, y - h / 2, w, h);
    } else {
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(x, y, w, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      context.closePath();
      context.fill();
    }
  }
  return canvas;
};

window.onload = function () {
  var oldCanvas = makeCanvas(),
      oldContext = oldCanvas.getContext('2d'),
      targetImage = document.getElementById('targetImage'),
      downloadContainer = document.getElementById('downloadContainer'),
      selectCanvas = document.getElementById('selectCanvas'),
      selectContext = selectCanvas.getContext('2d'),
      width = selectCanvas.width = oldCanvas.width,
      height = selectCanvas.height = oldCanvas.height;
  selectContext.fillStyle = '#000';
  downloadContainer.style.left = width + 25 + 'px';
  var clipCanvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
      clipContext = clipCanvas.getContext('2d');
  downloadContainer.appendChild(clipCanvas);
  selectCanvas.onmousedown = function (event) {
    var x0 = Math.max(0, Math.min(event.clientX, width)),
        y0 = Math.max(0, Math.min(event.clientY, height));
    targetImage.style.display = 'none';
    function update(event) {
      var x = Math.max(0, Math.min(event.clientX, width)),
          y = Math.max(0, Math.min(event.clientY, height)),
          dx = x - x0, w = Math.abs(dx),
          dy = y - y0, h = Math.abs(dy);
      selectContext.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
      selectContext.fillRect(x0, y0, dx, dy);
      clipCanvas.width = w;
      clipCanvas.height = h;
      if (w*h == 0) {
        downloadContainer.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      } else {
        downloadContainer.style.visibility = 'visible';
        clipContext.drawImage(oldCanvas,
          x0 + Math.min(0, dx), y0 + Math.min(0, dy), w, h,
          0, 0, w, h);
        downloadContainer.style.visibility = (w*h == 0 ? 'hidden' : 'visible');
        downloadContainer.style.top = Math.min(y0, y) + 'px';
      }
    };
    update(event);
    selectCanvas.onmousemove = update;
    document.onmouseup = function (event) {
      selectCanvas.onmousemove = undefined;
      document.onmouseup = undefined;
      targetImage.src = clipCanvas.toDataURL();
      targetImage.style.display = 'block';
    };
  };
};
```

```css
body, div, canvas, img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#targetImage {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
#oldCanvas, #selectCanvas, #downloadContainer {
  position: fixed;
}
#downloadContainer {
  visibility: hidden;
}
#downloadContainer .label {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  bottom: -20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #444;
}
#selectCanvas {
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="oldCanvas"></canvas>

<canvas id="selectCanvas"></canvas>

<div id="downloadContainer">
  <div class="label"> right-click above to download this image </div>
  <img id="targetImage">
</div>
```

Comment: This is very elaborate example, but I need to do that programatically, though this snipet will be definitelly useful for others! Thanks for your help!

Comment: What exactly do you want to do programmatically?