# How to show the blue select boundary of the selected object outside the canvas boundary (Fabric JS)?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabric js v4.1.0 and I would like to show the blue select boundary of the selected object outside the canvas boundary if it is partially dragged out of canvas and have the scaling and rotate functions also in this as the object which is selected inside the canvas.

Here is a demo of my current code https://codepen.io/raja-basumatary/pen/qBZGobQ

```
function isCanvasSupported() {
   var elem = document.createElement("canvas");
   return !!(elem.getContext && elem.getContext("2d"));
}

if (!isCanvasSupported()) {
   document.getElementById("nocanvas").className = "";
   document.getElementById("myCanvas").className = "hidden";
} else {
   // Constants
   var canvasHeight = 580;
   var canvasWidth = 865;

   var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("myCanvas");
   canvas.setHeight(canvasHeight);
   canvas.setWidth(canvasWidth);

   var rect = new fabric.Rect({
      left: 150,
      top: 100,
      fill: "#eef",
      width: 150,
      height: 250
   });

   canvas.add(rect);
}
```

I want something like this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTO7w.jpg)

Comment: You can only do this if the object is inside the canvas because it is area where you can draw; Work around can be faking canvas region like make canvas full region but show a smaller black rectangle

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava Thank you. But if I want to download that clipped area how do I achieve that.

Comment: You can refer to clip function as shown here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_clip

Comment: Also you can export it like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32256567/save-only-a-certain-part-of-an-html-canvas

Comment: Thank you it helped me a lot - @ShubhamSrivastava