# Convert SVG groups into multiple "individual" PNG files

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, png, fabricjs

I have an SVG file containing multiple  tags. When loading the file into an HTML canvas, the groups are recognised as separate objects. However, I would like to use javascript / Node to convert each of these separate objects into their respective image PNG URI string.

So for example inputting an SVG file with 3 objects should return a list with 3 PNG URI strings for each of the objects. I have been thinking about this a lot and searched all over the web for a similar issue without finding anything helpful.

My main thought at the moment is to make use of `canvas.toDataURL()` , however this converts the entire canvas and not individual objects. Would be nice with a function that is like `object.toDataURL()`, but that doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the bounds of an SVG element using `getBBox()` or `getBoundingClientRect()`. You could use that info to work out where on your Canvas that element is.  Then [copy that portion of your Canvas to an offscreen Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32256567/save-only-a-certain-part-of-an-html-canvas) of the right size. Then do whatever you like with that new Canvas image.