# Can I Save only a specific item of an HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, easeljs

I've already known that there is a similar question "Save only a certain part of an HTML canvas" been solved.
[Save only a certain part of an HTML canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32256567/save-only-a-certain-part-of-an-html-canvas)

However, my question is
**if there are many sprites drawn on one canvas, can I save only one certain sprite of them?**

Thank you~

Comment: Sure, clear the whole canvas, redraw only the one you want, export, optionnaly re-clear all + redraw all if you want to go back to the previous state. You could also draw that sprite on another canvas, that might be best depending on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, perhaps the easiest way is to cache the item you want, and then export its `cacheCanvas`, which is the off-screen canvas that is created as the object cache.